# ¿Como puedo dar tiempo limitado a los eventos de una tabla Mysql y PHP?

Tags: mysql, mysqli, php7

Buenas Tardes a todos disculpa por mi pequeña molestia.

Tengo una pequeña duda, estoy intentando dar tiempo a cada evento que ingresa a la tabla Evento de la db en la columna duración, lo que quiero realizar es un conteo que disminuya hasta llegar a "0" y luego que se elimine todo la fila de  la tabla automáticamente.

Mi tabla es algo asi:

Tabla "Evento"

```
id    nombre       datalles   fecha       duracion
1     ticket_Rock  Solo rock  16/02/2018  24h
2     ticket_otros Solo otros 18/02/2018  48h
```

se usa CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  en la columna "duracion" esta ahí creo que estoy bien... les agradecería mucho por sus ayudas.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que le estás dando el enfoque equivocado, generalmente lo que se hace no es tener un valor en la base de datos que tiene que estar mutando a uno nuevo según pase el tiempo, lo que se hace es poner una fecha_fin por ejemplo con la fecha en que se pierde la validez del registro.

Así puedes:

- Consultar por esa fecha para no mostrar los registros.
- usar algún tipo de cronjob o proceso que te borre todos los eventos fuera de esa fecha.

MySql te da algunas funciones para calcular fechas y sumarles tiempos.

http://www.linuxhispano.net/2010/07/06/suma-y-resta-de-fechas-con-mysql/

Saludos